# TypeError in Python Telegram bot script

Tags: python, typeerror, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
> """TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> c:\Users\Sharif\Desktop\py\pybot.py in line 85
> 82     updater.idle()
> 84 if __name__ == '__main__':
> 85     main()
> 
> c:\Users\Sharif\Desktop\py\pybot.py in line 61, in main()
> 59 def main():
> 60     # Create an instance of Updater with the received token
> 61     updater = Updater(token='token', use _context=True)
> 63     # Create a dispatcher for the bot
> 64     dispatcher = updater .dispatcher
> 
> 
> 
> Type Error: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'"""
```

The following error was from a Telegram bot script. My script is experiencing an `unexpected keyword argument` and I don't understand why.

Comment: don't you read the post before you press send and see that it is not what you want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a version problem, try to install `python-telegram-bot` version compatible with your code. You seem to have installed latest version of the package where the only arguments and attributes are now `bot` and `update_queue` based on the [documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html).